# How to redirect the LoginActivity to MainActivity from SplashScreenActivity after once user logged in

Tags: android

I tried a lot but all the time I run my app.. After splash screen, google signin activity opens evenif user already logged in through google account.once user logged in, I want to skip login activity .

Any
 suggestion will be appreciated. You are requested to please answer with appropriate code.

**Here is my SplashScreen code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     protected int _splashTime = 3000;
     ImageView imageViewLogo, imageViewText;
     Animation animationSlideUp;
     Animation animationFadeIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewLogo = findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogo);
        imageViewText = findViewById(R.id.imageViewText);

        animationSlideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_up_anim);
    imageViewLogo.startAnimation(animationSlideUp);


    animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_anim);
    imageViewText.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);

    Thread splashTread;


    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(_splashTime);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {
                finish();


                //login value is no, so start loginactivity

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


                //stop();
            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
}


}
```

**Here is my login code :**

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//a constant for detecting the login intent result
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 234;

//Tag for the logs optional
private static final String TAG = "AMOLEDify";

//creating a GoogleSignInClient object
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

//And also a Firebase Auth object
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    //first we intialized the FirebaseAuth object
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Then we need a GoogleSignInOptions object
    //And we need to build it as below
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    //Then we will get the GoogleSignInClient object from GoogleSignIn class
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    //Now we will attach a click listener to the sign_in_button
    //and inside onClick() method we are calling the signIn() method that will open
    //google sign in intent
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInProfile.class));
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //if the requestCode is the Google Sign In code that we defined at starting
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        //Getting the GoogleSignIn Task
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            //Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            //authenticating with firebase
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    //getting the auth credential
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });
}

//this method is called on click
private void signIn() {
    //getting the google signin intent
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

    //starting the activity for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Please use SharedPerference or Sqlite Database to create the session while accessing all the data from first time.

Comment: Are you using `Firebase` for login?

Comment: read about SharedPrefrences on developer.android.com you will found solution and always try to search on Stackoverflow before ask question

Comment: i am using google for log in

Comment: i tried so many solutions provided on stackoverflow but it didn't work.

Comment: when the credentials are correct create shredprefrences and store value like true, or false or anithing elese like user id and in your splash screen cheack whtere shredprference value store or not if stored redirect to min screen other wise login

Comment: can you please tell me which place i should write code for shared preference as i already tried it previously.. but my app crashed. it didn't work. hope my code was wrong or wrongly placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to that by simply checking in your `SplashActivity` is user already logged in:

```
  GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
  if(account != null){ 
    // user is logged in
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
 else {
//user is not logged in
  Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d("Already signed in", "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInProfile.class));
        //result(result);
    } else {
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {

                //result(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
```

Put this code in your onStart function and check already loggined or not